# Can Trivium ciphertext be decrypted by an adversary if the key is known, but the IV is not?

Tags: stream-cipher, pseudo-random-function, initialization-vector, attack, complexity

Suppose that the adversary is able to recover the key of Trivium cipher. But the associated IV is unknown to him. Will he be able to decrypt the ciphertexts without any complexity?

Comment: I'd study Trivium's security argument and determine if it falls apart in the situation.

Comment: Trivium uses [80-bit IV](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/79889/18298) which means that an attacker has 80-bit key search space like the [total computing power of Bitcoin miners](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298) can find the IV. Not that the IV is not meant to be secret.